# Adding month to yyyymm format

Tags: php, date, addition

I need to add a month for the date format yyyymm. For eg. '201312' would result in '201401'. Here's what I have currently and it's not working correctly.

```
function addMonth($year_month){
$year_month = (int) $year_month;
if($year_month%100 == 1) {return $year_month-89;}
return $year_month+1;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is easier if you use `DateTime()`

```
function addMonth($year_month){
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ym', $year_month);
    $date->modify('+1 month');
    return $date->format('Ym');
}
```

Alternative using `DateInterval()`

```
function addMonth($year_month){
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ym', $year_month);
    $date->add(new DateInterval('P1M'));
    return $date->format('Ym');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick to integers try:

```
function addMonth($year_month){
    $year_month = (int) $year_month;
    if($year_month%100 == 12)
        return $year_month+89;
    else
        return $year_month+1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A date time solution like John Condes is probably better, however if you want to roll your own for experience's sake, something like that below will work.

Using div and [modulos](http://www.php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.mod.php) to ensure you are in the right frames will work better if you for some reason need to add 2 months, you won't end up with a 13th month.

```
<?
function addMonth($year_month, $add=1){
    $year_month = (int) $year_month + $add;

    $month = $year_month % 100;
    $year = (int)($year_month / 100 + $month / 12) ;

    $month = (int)($month % 12);
    return $year * 100 + $month;
}

print addMonth("200101"); echo "\n";
print addMonth("200101",14); echo "\n";
print addMonth("200112"); echo "\n";
?>
```

[On Codepad this outputs](http://codepad.org/87svym9F):

```
200102
200203
200201
```

You can shorten it further if needed to this, but must less than this begins looking unreadable):

```
function addMonth($year_month, $add=1){
    $year_month = (int) $year_month + $add;
    $months = $year_month % 100;
    return (int)($year_month / 100 + $months / 12) * 100 + (int)($months % 12);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Much simpeler:

```
$month = 201712 ;
$nextMonth = date("Ym", strtotime($month . '01 + 1 month'));
echo $nextMonth ;
```

Result:

```
201801
```